# How to convert a pair of iterator into a view?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have a pair of iterator, and I would like to use `ranges::views::filter(some_predicate)` on it (with the pipe operator). AFAIU I should first convert my pair of iterator into a view. I tried to use `ranges::subrange(first, last)` to do so, but I’m getting horrible error messages.

Note1: I’m using C++14 and range-v3 version 0.9.1 (the last version compatible with gcc-5.5). If the solution differs when using C++17/20 and/or when using C++20 std::ranges, I’m also interested to know what changed.

Note2: I find the [documentation](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) of range-v3 severely lacking, so I’m using [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view). If you know a better documentation, I’m very interested.

---

EDIT:

In my real code, I’m wrapping a java-style legacy iterator (that has a `next()` method instead of `operator++`/`operator*`. I’m wrapping them in a C++-compatible wrapper. Then I tried to convert that wrapper into a view, and finally filter it. I reproduce a minimal example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n7W5rKxra). This use `iterator_range` as suggested, but it still doesn’t compile (see the second edit below).

```cpp
#include "range/v3/all.hpp"
#include "range/v3/iterator_range.hpp"

class LegacyIteratorWrapper {
public:
    using value_type = int;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    // The type isn’t default-constructible, the error comes from here
    LegacyIteratorWrapper() = delete;

    static LegacyIteratorWrapper create();
    
    reference operator*() const;
    pointer operator->();
    LegacyIteratorWrapper& operator++();
    LegacyIteratorWrapper operator++(int);
    friend bool operator==(const LegacyIteratorWrapper& a, const LegacyIteratorWrapper& b);
    friend bool operator!=(const LegacyIteratorWrapper& a, const LegacyIteratorWrapper& b);
};

void foo()
{
    LegacyIteratorWrapper begin { LegacyIteratorWrapper::create() };
    LegacyIteratorWrapper end { LegacyIteratorWrapper::create() };
    ranges::iterator_range<LegacyIteratorWrapper, LegacyIteratorWrapper> rng {begin, end};
    auto _ = rng
        | ranges::views::filter(
            [&](auto _) { return true; }
          )
        ;
}
```

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/functional/reference_wrapper.hpp:24:0,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/detail/variant.hpp:33,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/iterator/common_iterator.hpp:26,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/view/interface.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/view/ref.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/action/action.hpp:29,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/action.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/all.hpp:17,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/functional/pipeable.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr auto ranges::operator|(Arg&&, Pipe) [with Arg = ranges::iterator_range<LegacyIteratorWrapper, LegacyIteratorWrapper>&; Pipe = ranges::views::view<ranges::make_pipeable_fn::operator()(Fun) const [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::cpp20_filter_fn, foo()::<lambda(auto:15)> >]::_>; bool CPP_false_ = false; typename concepts::detail::identity<typename std::enable_if<(static_cast<bool>(((! is_pipeable_v<Arg>) && is_pipeable_v<Pipe>)) || CPP_false_), void>::type>::invoke<int> <anonymous> = 0]':
<source>:33:11:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/functional/pipeable.hpp:63:53: error: no matching function for call to 'ranges::pipeable_access::impl<ranges::views::view<ranges::make_pipeable_fn::operator()(Fun) const [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::cpp20_filter_fn, foo()::<lambda(auto:15)> >]::_> >::pipe(ranges::iterator_range<LegacyIteratorWrapper, LegacyIteratorWrapper>&, ranges::views::view<ranges::make_pipeable_fn::operator()(Fun) const [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::cpp20_filter_fn, foo()::<lambda(auto:15)> >]::_>&)'
             return pipeable_access::impl<Pipe>::pipe(static_cast<Arg &&>(arg), pipe);
                                                     ^
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/range_fwd.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/action/action.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/action.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/all.hpp:17,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:114:35: note: candidate: template<class Rng, class Vw> static constexpr auto ranges::views::view<View>::pipe(Rng&&, Vw&&, concepts::detail::enable_if_t<concepts::detail::Nil, (static_cast<bool>((viewable_range<Rng> && invocable<View&, Rng>)) || concepts::detail::CPP_false(concepts::detail::Nil{}))>) [with Rng = Rng; Vw = Vw; View = ranges::make_pipeable_fn::operator()(Fun) const [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::cpp20_filter_fn, foo()::<lambda(auto:15)> >]::_]
             static constexpr auto CPP_fun(pipe)(Rng && rng, Vw && v)( //
                                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:114:35: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>: In function 'void foo()':
<source>:33:11: error: 'void _' has incomplete type
           )
           ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/functional/reference_wrapper.hpp:24:0,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/detail/variant.hpp:33,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/iterator/common_iterator.hpp:26,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/view/interface.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/view/ref.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/action/action.hpp:29,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/action.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/all.hpp:17,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/functional/pipeable.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr auto ranges::operator|(Arg&&, Pipe) [with Arg = ranges::iterator_range<LegacyIteratorWrapper, LegacyIteratorWrapper>&; Pipe = ranges::views::view<ranges::make_pipeable_fn::operator()(Fun) const [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::cpp20_filter_fn, foo()::<lambda(auto:15)> >]::_>; bool CPP_false_ = false; typename concepts::detail::identity<typename std::enable_if<(static_cast<bool>(((! is_pipeable_v<Arg>) && is_pipeable_v<Pipe>)) || CPP_false_), void>::type>::invoke<int> <anonymous> = 0]':
<source>:33:11:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/functional/pipeable.hpp:63:53: error: no matching function for call to 'ranges::pipeable_access::impl<ranges::views::view<ranges::make_pipeable_fn::operator()(Fun) const [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::cpp20_filter_fn, foo()::<lambda(auto:15)> >]::_> >::pipe(ranges::iterator_range<LegacyIteratorWrapper, LegacyIteratorWrapper>&, ranges::views::view<ranges::make_pipeable_fn::operator()(Fun) const [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::cpp20_filter_fn, foo()::<lambda(auto:15)> >]::_>&)'
             return pipeable_access::impl<Pipe>::pipe(static_cast<Arg &&>(arg), pipe);
                                                     ^
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/range_fwd.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/action/action.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/action.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/all.hpp:17,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:114:35: note: candidate: template<class Rng, class Vw> static constexpr auto ranges::views::view<View>::pipe(Rng&&, Vw&&, concepts::detail::enable_if_t<concepts::detail::Nil, (static_cast<bool>((viewable_range<Rng> && invocable<View&, Rng>)) || concepts::detail::CPP_false(concepts::detail::Nil{}))>) [with Rng = Rng; Vw = Vw; View = ranges::make_pipeable_fn::operator()(Fun) const [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::cpp20_filter_fn, foo()::<lambda(auto:15)> >]::_]
             static constexpr auto CPP_fun(pipe)(Rng && rng, Vw && v)( //
                                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.9.1/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:114:35: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>: In function 'void foo()':
<source>:33:11: error: 'void _' has incomplete type
           )
           ^
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

---

EDIT2 (SOLVED): I got an error because `LegacyIteratorWrapper` isn’t default constructible. This is required to satisfy the regular trait (emulated by range-v3), which is required by C++ iterator, and which include being default-constructible.

Comment: Please post your example _here_, not on GodBolt, and provide (some of) the error message. Also please make it clearer whether you're interested in a C++14 solution (or any other specific version of the language standard).

Comment: Done. I’m interested on a C++14 solution with ranges-v3 0.9.1, because I need it right now, but I’m also interested in later version for my general understanding.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In ranges-v3, there is [`iterator_range`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1iterator__range.html) which you can use to wrap the iterators into a range object.

In C++20, you can use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) to wrap those iterators into an range object

Comment: I tried it (and I’m able to create the `iterator_range`), but I still can’t pipe it into `filter`, as you can see in the [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n7W5rKxra) link I added into the OP.

Comment: I don't think `std::span` applies to OP's case. And you can't make two arbitrary iterators into a span.

Comment: This answer should be improved by using [`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange)

Answer (score 3):

> I have a pair of iterator, and I would like to use `ranges::views::filter(some_predicate)` on it (with the pipe operator). AFAIU I should first convert my pair of iterator into a view. I tried to use `ranges::subrange(first, last)` to do so, but I’m getting horrible error messages.

Since you haven't really given a code backing up your *getting horrible error messages*, here's a code that defines two iterators on a vector, makes use of `ranges::subrange`, and filters the resulting range.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/subrange.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace r = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::views;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
    auto even = [](auto x){ return x % 2 == 0; };
    auto i1 = v.begin() + 1;
    auto ie = v.end() - 1;
    auto w = r::subrange(i1, ie) | rv::filter(even);
    for (auto i : w) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you clarify *what* your sample code is and what the errors you get, I or someone else could be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: I added a [minimal example](https://godbolt.org/z/n7W5rKxra) on the OP. You are right, I should have added it since the beginning.

Comment: @Robin, I don't have time at the moment to look at it. However I'd suggest that you try to strip down the problem and make it minimal. It doesn't look minimal as it is now.

Comment: Each time I tried to cut it down, it was compiling, until I finally understood the error, it’s because my `LegacyIteratorWrapper` wasn’t default-constructible. I will update the OP accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each pair of equal Iterators to a [`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange) with:

```
auto my_range = std::ranges::subrange{begi,endi};
```