# How to create ranges from two iterators

Tags: c++, c++20

Am new to using c++20 ranges.  One question I have is if you have two iterators into a vector how do you create a ranges view from them ? Range would start at first iterator and end 1 before the second iterator.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67007908/how-to-convert-a-pair-of-iterator-into-a-view

Comment: Thanks found it in your link

Comment: From a `vector` or other contiguous container you could also just use `std::span`. It has some convenience functions for getting subranges. Only if your code must be generic, or your iterators might be more complex (e.g. reversing, or from filter/transform views, etc.) is `ranges::subrange` needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange) allows combining together an iterator and a sentinel into a single view.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    std::vector v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::ranges::subrange w(v.begin(), v.begin() + 2);
    
    for (auto i : w)
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```